# If a Banach / Fréchet manifold $M$ happens to be a topological vector space, is $M$ just a Banach / Fréchet space?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, frechet-manifold

In finite dimensions, if $M$ is a smooth manifold that happens to be a vector space, then it is indeed just the Euclidean space.

I wonder if the same result holds valid in infinite dimensions. More specifically, let $B$ be a Banach space and $S$ be a nuclear Fréchet space.

Then,

> If $M$ is a Banach manifold modelled on $B$ and a topological vector space at the same time, can we conclude that $M=B$?

> Similarly, if $M$ is a Fréchet manifold modelled on $S$ and a topological vector space at the same time, can we conclude that $M=S$?

I think these are quite plausible, but I cannot see how to justify rigorously. Could anyone please help me?

Add : The meaning of $M=B$ or $M=S$ is that we can give the structure of a Banach / Frechet space on $M$ in a way that there exists a surjective linear isometry between $M$ and $B$ or $S$.

Comment: What does your notation $M=B$ mean? If it means homeomorphism, your statement about the finite dimensional case should be amended to [exclude dimension 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_R4), but maybe you meant that implicitly.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine I was thinking of surjective linear isometry between $M$ and $B$. I am a bit confused about dimension $4$. According to your link, there is not even a surjective isometry for exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Comment: @IgorKhavkine but can't I just explicitly construct one myself by starting from a local chart together with  translation invariance of the norm? This seemingly blatant ciontradiction really confuses me...

Comment: I'm no expert on exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$, so I'll leave that for someone else to clarify. But I think it's clear that you should edit your question to clarify the meaning of the $=$ notation.

Comment: What do you mean by isometry? A priori $M$ is not assumed to have a given metric structure (e.g. in the fin-dim case you just have a manifold, not a Riemannian manifold)

Comment: @KevinCasto Sorry about causing confusions. I did not intend any metric on the tangent bundle. I clarified my point on the post.

Comment: *All* inf-dim separable Frechet spaces are homeomorphic (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson–Kadec_theorem), and certainly they aren't all isometric.

Comment: @KevinCasto $M$ above is modelled on a "specific" Frechet space $S$. And I am asking if $M$ can be endowed with the same metric as that "particular" $S$.

Comment: But your sense of "modelling" is only in the sense of manifolds, that is to say, local diffeomorphism

Comment: @KevinCasto Yes, but I impose the further condition that $M$ itself is a TVS. Plus, the result you quote does not seem relevant for this case anyway, as I only consider a "specific" $S$ for "modelling".

Comment: Suppose you have any two inf-dim separable Frechet spaces $S_1$ and $S_2$. Then they are homeomorphic, and therefore one can be "modelled" on the other in exactly the sense you mean. But in general they are not isometric.

Comment: @KevinCasto Well, the definition of a Banach / Frechet manifold assumes "smoothness" of the modelling. That is, the transition maps must be smooth. That said, my understanding is that the homeomorphism in the Anderson-Kadec theorem is not necessarily a smooth map... Have I missed something?

Comment: @KevinCasto can you submit this as an answer?  Because the currently accepted (alleged) answer does not seem to answer the question at all.

Comment: @NikWeaver If the homeomorphism proposed by Anderson-Kadec theorem is smooth, then I agree with his answer. But my understading is that the homemorphism is not necessarily smooth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under mild conditions frechet manifolds are homeomorphic if and only if they have the same homotopy type. For Hilbert manifolds this can be upgraded to diffeomorphism. See Henderson ‘infinite dimensional manifolds are open subsets of Hilbert space’

https://projecteuclid.org/journalArticle/Download?urlId=bams%2F1183530637

Comment: Thank you. I will look into the link carefully myself, but the "homeomorphism" there does not look like isometry. Am I correct?

Comment: You need to choose additional structure to speak of isometries. But even if you do i dont think you can make these isometries

Comment: I am sorry about not being clear on the word isometry. I just revised my post to make it clearer. Could you provide any opinion on this?

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @NikWeaver May I ask what you mean?

Comment: I'm not sure how I can ask that any more clearly.

Comment: @NikWeaver What do you mean by "this"?

Comment: @NikWeaver: I thought of my answer like this. If there is vector space structure (I assume addition and multiplication be continuous), the space is contractible, hence there must be a homeomorphism to the model, because they have the same homotopy type. In finite dimensions there are contractible manifolds of the same dimension which are not homeomorphic.

Comment: But the question was about the existence of a linear isometry, not a homeomorphism.

Comment: @ThomasRot I understand and agree with your statement. However, what I am curious about is existence of linear isometry as I clarified on my post. This is surely a stronger requirement than the known results provided by you.

Comment: I agree that this doesnt answer the clarified post. The intended meaning of = was not clear to me then. I can of course delete this answer if desired.

Answer (score 1):

By the Anderson-Kadec theorem, all infinite-dimensional separable Frechet spaces are homeomorphic. The paper cited in the other answer points out that every Frechet manifold has a unique smooth structure, meaning (I believe) that if your Frechet space also starts life with a given smooth structure, then it is diffeomorphic to a Hilbert space.

Comment: I am confused by your last statment. Every separable Hilbert space can be identified with $l^2(\mathbb{N})$ in a way that the inner product is preserved. That is, between any pair of separable Hilbert sapces, there is an inner-product-preserving isomorphism, which must therefore be smooth (=diffeomorphic).

Comment: Oops sorry good point, deleted last sentence

Comment: Thank you.  Then, my main question about the metric remains unsolved...Well, I think I have to figure it out myself. Anyway, thank you again for your detailed comments.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether there exist "exotic' Frechet spaces that are homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic; but for your question, the answer is no if there exist even a *single* pair of diffeomorphic Frechet/Banach spaces that are not isometric. I would imagine that e.g. $L^p(0,1)$ and $L^q(0,1)$ for $2 < p < q < \infty$ would be diffeomorphic.

Comment: I am still under the impression that your concern and my question are not on the same page. Look at the last sentence in my post.

Comment: "The meaning of $M=B$ or $M=S$ is that we can give the structure of a Banach / Frechet space on $M$ in a way that there exists a surjective linear isometry between $M$ and $B$ or $S$"
.

Comment: Note that $B$ or $S$ here are given spaces, and my understanding is that Anderson-Kadec theorem only guarantee a homemomorphism, NOT diffeomorphism. So, assuming "smooth modelling", my question is not contradicted by Anderson-Kadec theorem. I stated all these in the comments above.